# Wait until window closes when message loop is on another thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

In one C++ application I have a window whose message loop runs in a separate thread because the main thread is busy calculating and rendering a simulation. The window acts as a log window for the simulation. When the simulation throws an exception, the simulation closes and the log window displays the details.

Now the main thread should wait until the log window is closed. Since the message loop runs on a separate thread, I tried to

```
WaitForSingleObject(logwindow->thread, INFINITE);
```

from the main thread.

However, this seems to block the message pump and the log window freezes. So how do I correctly wait until a window is closed or a thread ends?

ED: The window is created on the main thread but runs on a different thread. I'll go ahead and change it so it creates on the message loop thread too.

Comment: in which thread was the window created originally? windows should not migrate between threads in WinAPI

Comment: ok, i'll make sure it gets created on the loop thread too.

Comment: `INFINITE` means just what you'd expect. If you never signal this thread it will wait forever. Either add code to signal the thread to continue or specify a timeout value instead of `INFINITE`. P.S. you can send a custom message to your other window when handling WM_CLOSE to let him know about it instead of blocking and just join the thread.

Comment: If you are creating it on the main thread then all its messages will be pumped by the main thread too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Run all the UI out of the main thread and get the worker thread to synchronize reporting back to the main thread to display, for example via `PostMessage` or `SendMessage`.
2. Don't wait at all and get the worker thread to post a message to the main thread when the worker is done.
3. Use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx) for your wait.

To elaborate on `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, it's a wait function that can be configured to return when messages arrive in the queue. Thus you can keep your message pump alive whilst also using a blocking wait in between processing queued messages.

In pseudo-code you would write it like this:

```
do
{    
    WaitResult = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS);
    if (WaitResult == MessageArrivedOnQueue) 
        PumpMessageQueue();
} while (WaitResult != WaitHandlesSignaled)
```

Comment: 3. would require the least changes to the code, I'll try that first.

Comment: Option 3 might be the easiest, but option 1 would be my recommendation.

Comment: Design-wise, 1. would work really better. I'll go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the log window is freezing while the main thread is in a blocking wait suggests the worker thread is sending a message to the main thread and then waiting for a reply, but the main thread is already blocked and cannot reply to it.  That is a classic deadlock situation for both threads.  You should use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` instead of `WaitForSingleObject()` in the main thread to detect when new messages need processing while waiting, eg:

```
do
{
    DWORD dwRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &(logwindow->thread), FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    if (dwRet == 0xFFFFFFFF) break;
    if (dwRet == (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1))
    {
      process messages here...
    }
}
while (dwRet != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

I agree with David that you really should be doing all UI work in the main thread and do your calculations in the worker thread, not the other way around.

Comment: It blocks the log window because the log window is actually created in the main thread and so uses the main thread message pump which is blocked by `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: That explains the log window freezing, but not why the worker thread is not terminating so `WaitForSingleObject()` can unblock.  Unless the worker thread is sending messages to the log window and becoming deadlocked since the messages cannot be processed.  Or if the main thread is not posting a `WM_QUIT` message to the worker thread's message queue.

Comment: Since app appears to be working, the window access from the worker thread works. Thus it is probably done through messages and thus synchronised onto the main thread, which owns the log window. I guess they deadlock if main thread is in WaitForSingleObject.